# Script executes all of the commands except one

Tags: shell, router

I'm new to this. I wrote this simple script for my Huawei B315s-22 router to update my he.net ddns every five minutes. Everything works fine, but when I put it on the autorun, the command "atc AT+CFUN=1" which will turn on the internet is not executed.
The command that turns off the internet is working fine: I tried it with the `echo` command and without it. I even tried "/system/xbin/atc AT+CFUN=1", and is still not working.
It works fine when I run the script "sh /online/he-ddns.sh".
What am I doing wrong ?

```
#!bin/sh

while :
do
publicip="echo `curl --max-time 5 ipinfo.io/ip`" 
wanip="echo `ifconfig wan0 2>/dev/null|awk '/inet addr:/ {print $2}'|sed 's/addr://'`"
if [ "$publicip" = "$wanip" ]; then
echo `curl --max-time 5 https://dyn.example.com:password@dyn.dns.he.net/nic/update?hostname=dyn.example.com`
else
echo `atc AT+CFUN=0`
sleep 4
echo `atc AT+CFUN=1`
fi
sleep 300
done
```

Edit: removed echo and backticks and it worked perfectly. thanks to all of you.

```
#!/bin/sh
while :
do
publicip=$( curl --max-time 5 ipinfo.io/ip)
wanip=$(ifconfig wan0 2>/dev/null|awk '/inet addr:/ {print $2}'|sed 's/addr://')
if [ "$publicip" = "$wanip" ]; then
curl --max-time 5 https://dyn.example.com:password@dyn.dns.he.net/nic/update?hostname=dyn.example.com
else
atc AT+CFUN=0
sleep 2
atc at+cfun=1
fi
sleep 300
done
```

Comment: See [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050), and specifically [5. I'm constructing a command based on information that is only known at run time](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050#I.27m_constructing_a_command_based_on_information_that_is_only_known_at_run_time) Bottom line, use an array to store separate arguments when building a command to execute.

Comment: You tagged the question `bash` but your shebang is `#!bin/sh` and should be `#!/bin/bash` (notice the absolute path)

Comment: Use https://www.shellcheck.net/

Comment: Don't use ```echo `somecommand` ```, just run `somecommand` directly -- the `echo` and the backticks mostly cancel each other out, except for adding the possibility of weird interactions (I don't think that's what's causing the command to fail, it's just a general bad idea). Also, I'm pretty sure they aren't always doing what you think. Putting `set -x` at the beginning of the script might clarify what it's doing as it runs.

Comment: I took the liberty to replace your _bash_ tag by _shell_, since there is no bash involved in your question.